# can any one explain in detail about the following program of pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void main(){
   char a[2][30]={"Don't walk in front of me..", "I am not follow"};
   printf("%c%c", *(a[0]+9), *(*(a+0)+5));
}
```

And the output of the program is

```
k
```

Comment: is the output "k" or "k " - i.e. with a space after it (which would be characters 9 and then 5 of the first 'string')?

Comment: yeah "k " is the output

Comment: The output is `k ` (with space). And the explanation of code fodder is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran it to check I was not insane : see the link here: https://onlinegdb.com/BJBdFKHhm if you change your output to somthing like: `"<%c%c>"` you will see your space...

Comment: yeah now I am able to see the space. But I'm not getting what is happening and how the output is <k >.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some example based explanations...

c-arrays can be accessed in two ways:

As an array:

```
char a[10] = "0123456789";
printf("%c", a[5]); // prints "5"
```

As a pointer:

```
char a[10] = "0123456789";
printf("%c", *(a + 5)); // prints "5"
```

In the second example we are just dereferencing `a` as a pointer to the start of the string plus 5.

This can be used for 2d, 3d, etc... arrays as well:

```
char a[2][10] = {"012", "abc"};
printf("%c", *(*(a + 0)+1)); // prints "1"
printf("%c", *(*(a + 1)+1)); // prints "b"
```

You can mix the two methods:

```
printf("%c", *(a[0] + 1); // prints "1"
printf("%c", *(a + 1)[1]; // prints "b"
```

And just for completeness (this could be considered the "normal" way to access the array values):

```
printf("%c", a[0][1]; // prints "1"
printf("%c", a[1][1]; // prints "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

The output is not `k` but `k[WHITESPACE]`.
In C, all variables are numbers. Pointers too.

---

### First `%c`

`*(a[0] + 9)`

`a[0]` is a pointer, so a number corresponding to the `a[0]`th memory byte. If you add 9 to it you get 9 bytes further.

`a[0]` points to the first character of `"Don't walk in front of me"` : `D`
Then if you add 9 to `a[0]` you get the address of the tenth character in the string : `k`

the `*()` indicates that you don't want the value of `a[0] + 9` (0x*hexNumber*) but the value *addressed by* `a[0] + 9` : k (107)

---

### Second `%c`

`*(*(a+0)+5))`

- `*(a + 0)` is the value pointed by `a + 0` : `a[0]`
- `*(a[0] + 5)` : Should I really re-explain this ??

Hope this answers your question !

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `char` array `a` like this:

```
char a[2][30]={{"Don't walk in front of me.."}, //a[0][30]
              // 0123456789 - *(a[0]+9) is a[0][9] is `k`
              // 012345 - *(*(a+0)+5) is is a[0][5] is ' '
               {"I am not follow"}}; //a[1][30]
```

So the output would be `k` followed by space. You may not be able to see the space on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[2][30]
```

This tells the program to make a 2D array of 2x30 chars on the stack. It's a just a continuous block of 60 `chars`, but allows the program to know the correct position you're trying to access when using notation such as a[2][3].

```
{"Don't walk in front of me..", "I am not follow"};
```

This is the so-called "string literal initializer for character and wide character arrays". The array gets filled with the content of those string literals (which includes a `'\0'` at the end). Note that this doesn't fill up all 60 chars, the rest after the null terminators also gets filled up with `'\0'`.

```
printf("%c%c",
```

This prints two characters that are specified in following arguments of the call.

```
*(a[0]+9)
```

This takes the address of the first string, adds `9` to it and thus gets the address of the `k` in `walk`. It is then dereferenced, resulting in the char `k`.

```
*(*(a+0)+5));
```

This does something very similar, just instead of `a[0]` it is written as `*(a+0)`. Instead of `9` you're only adding `5`, so instead of the `'k'` you end up getting `' '` (the space between the words `Don't` and `walk`).

That's how it's printing `"k "` (that's a `k` and a space, not just a `k`.).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I added it to the answer.

Comment: thank you. and I want a clarification that, is a[0] and *(a+0) are same ? as you explained here This does something very similar, just instead of a[0] it is written as *(a+0).